# Basemap scatterplot (Matplotlib) - Error can't set attribute

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, scatter

I have been trying to add two lists of floats to a scatterplot using the Matplotlib. I have simply created a Basemap with mostly default settings. However, whenever I attempt to run the script I get the error below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def main():

    wmap = Basemap()

    wmap.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')

   wmap.fillcontinents(color='coral',lake_color='aqua')

    wmap.drawcoastlines()

    locationData = open("locationData", "r")

    lats = []

    lons = []

    ASN = []

    company = []

    fileLine = locationData.readlines()

    for i in fileLine:

        parsedLine = i.split(",")

        lats.append(float(parsedLine[0]))

        lons.append(float(parsedLine[1]))

        ASN.append(parsedLine[2])

        company.append(parsedLine[3])

    locationData.close()

    x,y = wmap(lats,lons)

    wmap.scatter(x,y)

    plt.show()


 if(__name__ == '__main__'):
        main()
```

I receive the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mapGen.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()
  File "mapGen.py", line 45, in main
    wmap.scatter(lats,lons)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages      /mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line 563, in with_transform
    return   plotfunc(self,x,y,*args,**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line 3253, in scatter
    self._restore_hold(ax)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line 3229, in _restore_hold
ax._hold = self._tmp_hold
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

I have tried changing around the attributes to wmap.scatter() and the variables, but there error still persists and I haven't been able to find documentation on this error. Any ideas?

Comment: You will need to upgrade matplotlib to version 3.0.2, or downgrade to 2.2.3. [This comment](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/435#issuecomment-436659524) summarizes the problem.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This specific exception is raised when the attribute you're trying to change is a property that doesn't have a setter. It seems the basemap change is needed, adding a setter would solve the issue.

But you can change `wmap.scatter(x,y)` to `plt.scatter(x, y)` to solve it.